# Android Canvas Development

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to android development, and I am doing development on android 4.0(ice cream sandwich),I actually don't know how to create canvas in an android app, and I need to create it and incorporate in my android app, (whenever the user will click that certain button I need canvas to be opened, I need help in both(xml & activity file)?

Comment: Have you googled atleast or not ?

Comment: You do not create a canvas.  You override `draw()` or `onDraw()` in a custom view.  The `Canvas` is passed as an argument to those methods.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [official guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html), it should answer everything.